# Why the color of gameobjects is different if i make new instance for color in script or select color from editor?

Tags: unity, c#

In the script top:

```
public Color blocksColor;
```

Then inside a method:

```
//block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = blocksColor;
block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(241, 255, 0, 255);
```

When i'm doing the instance of the color my self with the values 244,255,0,255 the color is just like what i wanted.

[image: color fine]

But if i'm using the color from the variable:

```
block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = blocksColor;
```

And in the editor i'm setting the color to be with the same values:
Now the color is not even close to what it was when i was setting the color with my own instance in the script:

In the inspector it seems like the same color but the grid color is not the same.

[image: color]

The complete code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridBlock;
    public int gridWidth = 10;
    public int gridHeight = 10;
    public float spaceBetweenBlocks = 1.5f;
    public Vector3 blocksScale = new Vector3(1, 0.01f, 1);
    public Color blocksColor;

    private GameObject[] wallsParents = new GameObject[4];
    public GameObject[] allBlocks;

    void Start()
    {
        wallsParents[0] = GameObject.Find("Top Wall");
        wallsParents[1] = GameObject.Find("Left Wall");
        wallsParents[2] = GameObject.Find("Right Wall");
        wallsParents[3] = GameObject.Find("Bottom Wall");

        GenerateGrid();
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        var findpath = GetComponent<PathFinder>();
        findpath.FindPath();
    }

    public void AutoGenerateGrid()
    {
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        for (int i = 0; i < allBlocks.Length; i++)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(allBlocks[i]);
        }

        var end = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("End");
        DestroyImmediate(end);

        GenerateGrid();
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        var findpath = GetComponent<PathFinder>();
        findpath.FindPath();
    }

    public void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z++)
            {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(gridBlock, Vector3.zero, gridBlock.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                block.transform.parent = transform;
                block.transform.name = "Block";
                block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * spaceBetweenBlocks, 0, z * spaceBetweenBlocks);
                block.transform.localScale = blocksScale;
                block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = blocksColor;
                //block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(241, 255, 0, 255);

                if (x == 0)//TOP
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[0].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "TopWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
                else if (z == 0)//LEFT
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[1].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "LeftWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
                else if (z == gridHeight - 1)//RIGHT
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[2].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "RightWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }

                else if (x == gridWidth - 1)//BOTTOM
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[3].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "BottomWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the code.

Comment: Are you setting the color in the Start() method, or the Update() method?

Comment: @XenoRo added the complete code.

Comment: @Stephan I'm calling it from the Start and changing the color in the inspector before running the game. Then running the game and in the Start it's calling GenerateGrid and should change the color but the color is not the same as when making the instance.

Comment: this might be a lighting issue. where is your light in the scene?

Comment: @Stephan Here is a link for a screenshot of the scene showing the lights. The cube that i'm using to crate the grid is the one on the right.  But if the it's the lights problem why when i create instance in the code it's working fine ? https://imgur.com/a/os7dH

Comment: Does it still look right if you drop one of your prefabs in the scene and run it?

Comment: I found that if i add another spotlight above the grid it will make the colors the same.  Still not sure why when setting the color with instance it's working fine but when setting the color from the inspector it's not the same. So i will add a constant spotlight above the grid but that's not a solution or it's not explaining what is the different between instance of color and assigning color.